# VS 2013 MVC 5 No Intellisense for HtmlHelpers in Area Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5, intellisense, html-helper

Project: VB.NET MVC5 w/ EF6, MvcScaffolding, and BootstrapEditorTemplates

Since this morning I don't get any intellisense for any of the built in MVC helpers, nor my custom ones in **any of the Views** in **an Area**.
NOTE: I can still see Html.Encode, and Htm.DropDownList (NOT DropDownListFor<>) etc.

If I build it I recieve errors, though I can still browse the application correctly and see the correct editors and data.

```
@ModelType Quotes4YouVB.Request
@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Urgency)
@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Message)
```

I recieve the following errors among other similar ones.

> 'ModelType' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its
>   protection level. 'ViewBag' is not declared. It may be inaccessible
>   due to its protection level. 'EditorFor' is not a member of
>   'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper'. 'ValidationMessageFor' is not a
>   member of 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper'.

I've tried all the usual suspects:

- Close and Re-open View
- Restart VS
- Delete /bin and /obj
- Tools / Imports and Export Settings / Reset All Settings
- Uninstall MvcScaffolding, T4Scaffolding and T4Scaffolding.Core
- Re-Installed MVC 5.2 to project through NuGet
- NuGet: Update-Package

Any ideas anyone? It seems odd that it's specific to /Areas/, it works completely fine in ~/Views/X/Y.vbhtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution! I'm unsure why this specific thing causes this problem, but as with most VS issues I'm not gonna question it too much, just gonna go with it haha.

It relates to the **System.Web.WebPages.Razor Host FactoryType** section.

My **~/Views/Web.config** has the following:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory,
    System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
    PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      ...
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Specifically the **Version=5.0.0.0** part. Because I'd just re-installed MVC 5.2.x from NuGet, so surely it should be 5.2.0.0?

I checked the Web.config in my ~/Areas/[AreaName]/Views/Web.Config and found that it had everything the same, except it read **Version=5.2.0.0**:

`<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />`

I tried both in both files and found that **wherever 5.0.0.0 is used then all intellisense works perfectly for those views**.

**So, the solution:** Modify all Web.config files to use a compatible version for the factoryType. (5.0.0.0 works for me, though 5.2.0.0 does not)

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <!--<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />-->
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

I'm really unsure about why this is happening though, if anyone has any further information or a better solution to use 5.2.0.0 then please share :)

Comment: I had the same problem after updating to MVC 5 from 4. I had replaced all the references to 4.0.0.0 ([as instructed](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)) but missed the `web.config` in my Area/Views folder.

Comment: Had this problem recently (now 2017), but thought I'd throw a comment in here mentioning this solved my problem, Im in MVC 5.3.2, but I had to set it to 5.2 for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I once had this problem. This solved my issue:

Open project's output folder in Windows explorer (usually **bin** folder at the root of the project) and delete everything in it. Then close the solution and reopen it.

Hope that helps.